# Python list to make a movement effect

Tags: python, list

I would like to code the following example, lets create a list `a=['.','.','.','.','.','.']` where `'.'` Is represented as empty terrain . A ball ( `char='o'`) should move forward toward the end of the list.
Have I to put a `.pop` and `.insert` method in a loop for making that movement effect?
Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post some code please.

Comment: you should write some effort, share with us and describe your problem clearly

Comment: @makutene, if one of the below answers helped, feel free to accept (tick on left) so other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is a trivial implementation of your algorithm:

```
a = ['.','.','.','.','.','.']

for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = 'o'
    print(''.join(a))
    a[i] = '.'

# o.....
# .o....
# ..o...
# ...o..
# ....o.
# .....o
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pop` and `insert` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)) to move the 'o' across the list.

```
a = ['o','.','.','.','.','.']

for _ in a:
    print(''.join(a))
    a.insert(0, a.pop())
```

Comment: i just meant in a single output line. As i could see at cli the ball moving. Like if i was a while loop where the ball is moving towards the end of list and then backward

Comment: @makutene When I run this code, that's what I see. Do you get something else?